# Error: Not found: 'dart:ui' export 'dart:ui' show Offset;

Tags: android-studio, flutter, dart

When i run on Android Studio

> flutter drive --target=test_driver/app.dart

And i got this output

> file:///C:/flutter/packages/flutter_test/lib/src/accessibility.dart:8:8:
>   Error: Not found: 'dart:ui' import 'dart:ui' as ui;
>
> file:///C:/flutter/packages/flutter_test/lib/src/binding.dart:9:8:
>   Error: Not found: 'dart:ui' import 'dart:ui' as ui;
>          ^
>
> file:///C:/flutter/packages/flutter_test/lib/src/matchers.dart:8:8:
>   Error: Not found: 'dart:ui' import 'dart:ui' as ui;
>          ^
>
> file:///C:/flutter/packages/flutter_test/lib/src/matchers.dart:9:8:
>   Error: Not found: 'dart:ui' import 'dart:ui';
>
> file:///C:/flutter/packages/flutter_test/lib/src/test_pointer.dart:12:1:
>   Error: Not found: 'dart:ui' export 'dart:ui' show Offset; ^
>
> file:///C:/flutter/packages/flutter_test/lib/src/window.dart:6:8:
>   Error: Not found: 'dart:ui' import 'dart:ui' hide window;
>
> file:///C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/rendering/box.dart:6:8:
>   Error: Not found: 'dart:ui' import 'dart:ui' as ui show lerpDouble;
>
> file:///C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/rendering/debug_overflow_indicator.dart:6:8:
>   Error: Not found: 'dart:ui' import 'dart:ui' as ui;
>
> file:///C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/rendering/editable.dart:6:8:
>   Error: Not found: 'dart:ui' import 'dart:ui' as ui show TextBox,
>   lerpDouble;
>
> file:///C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/rendering/error.dart:5:8:
>   Error: Not found: 'dart:ui' import 'dart:ui' as ui show Paragraph,
>   ParagraphBuilder, ParagraphConstraints, ParagraphStyle,
>
> Stopping application instance. Driver tests failed: 254

My flutter doctor -v

> [√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK
>   version 29.0.2)
>       • Android SDK at C:\Users\ROG\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
>       • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
>       • Platform android-29, build-tools 29.0.2
>       • ANDROID_HOME = C:\Users\ROG\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
>       • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
>       • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b03)
>       • All Android licenses accepted.
>
> [√] Chrome - develop for the web
>       • Chrome at C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
>
> [!] Visual Studio - develop for Windows (Visual Studio Community 2017
>   15.9.7)
>       • Visual Studio at C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community
>       • Visual Studio Community 2017 version 15.9.28307.423
>       X Visual Studio is missing necessary components. Please re-run the Visual Studio installer for the "Desktop development with C++"
>   workload, and include these components:
>           MSBuild
>           VC++ 2017 version 15.9 v14.16 latest v141 tools
>           Windows 10 SDK (10.0.17763.0)
>
> [√] Android Studio (version 3.5)
>       • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
>       • Flutter plugin version 40.2.2
>       • Dart plugin version 191.8593
>       • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b03)
>
> [√] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2019.2)
>       • IntelliJ at G:\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.2.3
>       • Flutter plugin version 40.2.4
>       • Dart plugin version 192.7402
>
> [√] VS Code, 64-bit edition (version 1.29.1)
>       • VS Code at C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code
>       • Flutter extension version 2.21.1
>
> [√] Connected device (3 available)
>       • Samsung Galaxy S9 1 • 192.168.126.103:5555 • android-x86    • Android 8.0.0 (API 26)
>       • Windows             • Windows              • windows-x64    • Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18362.418]
>       • web                 • web                  • web-javascript • Google Chrome 78.0.3904.70
>
> ! Doctor found issues in 1 category.

Any thoughts?
Please help, thankyou so much

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your test file which has the driver does not contain any flutter-related imports.

so app_test should have nothing to do with flutter, only dart.